# Problema con navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-studio

Estoy realizando un proyecto con un Navigation drawer y al cargar el xml del MAin Activity se muestra una imagen que tengo de fondo pero al cargar cualquier fragment me muestra el contenido de dicho fragment pero con la imagen del Main Activity al fondo y no quiero que se vea, Alguin me pude ayudar con ese problemita.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);




    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
        this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

una forma es agregando esta propiedad
a cada layout de los fragments:

```
 android:background="?android:colorBackground"
```

Comment: Perfecto, con eso consigo justo lo que quiero. Muchisimas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Hola para poner imagen o color a cada xml de fragmento o activy que tengas solo haz esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]