# Ayuda con Navigation Drawer no se que frame referir en .replace(R.id)

Tags: android-studio, navigation-drawer

Estoy estancado hace dias en lo que pueda ser algo demasiado simple, pero como soy nuevo con Android Studio no se como solucionar.

Estoy practicando por primera vez con Navigation Drawer, y tengo ciertos botones en el layout de mi HomeFragment:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi problema está en que al darle click sobre el boton 1 el metodo de java no me lleva al fragment, y no quiero implementar intent para activity. Esto es lo que tengo:

```
    public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private HomeViewModel homeViewModel;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // el objeto root es de tipo vista, nos permite instanciar los elementos xml
        homeViewModel =
                ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_facul, container, false);
        
        final TextView textView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_home);
        final ImageButton img_btn_1 = root.findViewById(R.id.img_btn_1);

        final YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView = root.findViewById(R.id.youtube_player_view);

        homeViewModel.getText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
                textView.setText(s);

                getLifecycle().addObserver(youTubePlayerView)

                img_btn_1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
   
                        FragmentManager manager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                        Fragment1_btn1 fragment1 = new Fragment1_btn1();
                        manager.beginTransaction()
                                .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_rigth_to_left, 
                                 R.anim.exit_rigth_to_left,
                                        R.anim.enter_left_to_rigth, R.anim.exit_left_to_rigth)
                                .replace(R.id.cual_frame_pongo_aqui, fragment1)
                                .addToBackStack(null)
                                .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
                                .commit();
                    }
                });

            }
        });
        return root;
    }

}
```

Si se fijan en el `.replace(R.id.cual_frame_pongo_aqui, fragment1)` no se cual frame de todos los layout xml debo poner.

Estos son los layout xml que tengo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y de hecho al darle el frame contenedor que tengo en content_main.xml me lo muestra pero junto con todo lo del layout de los botones anterior, o sea no me desaparece el fragment anterior y veo todo junto.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: checa esta respuesta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/225437/problema-con-navigation-drawer/225484#225484

Comment: Gracias a armen por el dato, solo era de rellenar el fondo del xml del layout:  android:background="?android:colorBackground"